# How to change view controller using if statements

Tags: if-statement, uiviewcontroller

i want my app to change view controller with no animation when a certain condition is true. The code I'm using at the moment brings up no errors or issues but doesn't seem to work.

.h file

`-(void)levelTwo;`

.m file

```
-(void)levelTwo
{
    if (scoreNumber > 200) {
        UIStoryboard *mainstoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"storyboard" bundle:Nil];
        UIViewController *france = [mainstoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"france1"];
        [self presentViewController:france animated:NO completion:nil];
    }
}
```

Comment: Is `levelTwo` called?

Comment: And `scoreNumber > 200`?

Comment: Along with what @JoeFryer is saying, have you debugged this code by stepping through it? Are you hitting the breakpoint(s) as expected?

Comment: i have used the breakpoints and its not hitting them as expected its not even checking if the conditions are true. sorry not an expert in   this. so I'm guessing this is what you mean  ?